# Pass html and jquery value to PHP and MySQL table

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a personal project and I'm having some issues when trying to use the val(); function and then using it in my php script to I can successfully insert a row into my database table:

Here is my HTML Code:
http://www.icovi.com/stackoverflow/index.png

Here is my jQuery Code:
http://www.icovi.com/stackoverflow/jquery.png

Here is my PHP Code:
http://www.icovi.com/stackoverflow/php.png

For the jQuery code I'm using this following code:

```
var emm = $('#email').val();
$.post("submit.php", { "email": emm } );
```

^ This jQuery code is supposed to take the email value from the text input named "email" and then I would use it in my PHP Code and finally introduce it to my MySQL Database table:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sql="INSERT INTO people (id, email, time) VALUES ('','$email','2')";
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: The whole code seems good to me. Let's debug it. Can you alert (or console.log) the variable emm. Do you get the value? If that passes, can you print the variable $email in the php script? Is that value correct? If so, it would seem the problem is in the sql query. Is id an auto_increment field? It email a varchar field?

Comment: Hello I'll try not inserting into the database to see if getting the value is what is actually wrong or the query... And yes the ID is an auto-increment field and the email is varchar. thanks.

Comment: Reading your validation, it's very risky relying on keypress as you do. What happens if someone pastes using a mouse? You'd be probably better off implementing a tried and tested validation library like http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: You should edit your post to include the code here, in case the link goes out of date in the future.